# Room field / getter mismatch warning when using sealed classes or Any

Tags: android, kotlin, orm, android-room

I have a Room (`v2.4.0-beta01`) database, and whilst it works fine, during the build it gives a field vs getter mismatch warning on a few fields, included below.

I suspect this is due to an interop issue between Kotlin and Java, since the field definitions in the Kotlin and autogenerated Java don't perfectly match. Whilst the `Any` causing problems is understandable, I'd have expected the list of sealed class objects to work smoothly.

Any ideas how I can ideally resolve the warning, or at least let Room know it's not an issue?

PS: Class / variable names have been changed, for privacy & simplicity.

##### Warnings

```
com.example.Entity's myObjects field has type java.util.List<? extends com.example.MySealedClass> but its getter returns java.util.List<com.example.MySealedClass>. This mismatch might cause unexpected myObjects values in the database when com.example.Entity is inserted into database.
    private java.util.List<? extends com.example.MySealedClass> layoutElements;

com.example.Entity's myMap field has type java.util.Map<java.lang.String, ?> but its getter returns java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>. This mismatch might cause unexpected myMap values in the database when com.example.Entity is inserted into database.
    private java.util.Map<java.lang.String, ? extends java.lang.Object> myMap;
```

##### Entity.kt

```
    @ColumnInfo(name = "myObjects")
    var myObjects: List<MySealedClass> = listOf(),

    @ColumnInfo(name = "myMap")
    @TypeConverters(MyTypeConverter::class)
    var myMap: Map<String, Any>? = null,
```

##### Entity.java (Room generated)

```
    @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
    @androidx.room.ColumnInfo(name = "myObjects")
    private java.util.List<? extends com.example.MySealedClass> myObjects;

    @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable()
    @androidx.room.ColumnInfo(name = "myMap")
    private java.util.Map<java.lang.String, ? extends java.lang.Object> myMap;
```

##### MySealedClass.kt

```
    sealed class MySealedClass(val x: Int, val y: Boolean = false) : Serializable {
        data class InnerClass(private val z: Int) : MySealedClass(z), Serializable
        data class InnerClass2(private val zz: Int) : MySealedClass(z), Serializable
    }
```

Comment: I have the same issue. For some reason Room converts `List<SomeType>` to `java.util.List<? extends SomeType>`. Did you find any solutions to this warning?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same warning and resolved it by changing the data type of the Map from `<String, Any>` to `<String, *>`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).